# My Laptop gets hot on OpenSUSE

Tags: opensuse, fan

Recently I have installed openSUSE 12.3 on my Lenevo U410. I am using Windows on this machine too. But when I using openSUSE I realize that my laptop get much hotter than what is it in Windows. I also used Ubuntu before openSUSE. Ubuntu works fine, but now my fan works a little.

Do you know how to solve this?

Comment: What's the source of the issue? Try checking the sensors for temperature to be able to tell. My wild guess it's the GPU - if it's so, check which driver is used by Ubuntu (`lsmod | grep -P 'nvidia|nouveau'`) and which in openSUSE. If it's the same, you may want to investigate powersaving settings.

Comment: sorry for delayed answer. My sensors works well. I am using `sensors` command and get the temperatures correct. And all of them is working. About the driver, I search and find that driver. But is there a problem with using discrete GPU. My laptop has a intel GPU onboard and nvidia with optimus technology. (when laptop is idle it gets hot too, so I think this is not about GPU).

Comment: I rather meant whether you know what is making your laptop so hot.

Comment: How can I check my power saving options?

Comment: Lenovo has a tool on windows. I changed it to maximize battery lifespan and therefore my battery has a strange charging behaviour in both windows and openSUSE! Is there something like that for power saving?

Comment: when I type `sensors` there are two other temp than real on, "high" and "critical". Can I changed these values so my fan start working in low temps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally find the problem. The problem was from my discrete NVIDIA GPU. OpenSUSE 12.3 found it and all the drivers were good, but I do not know why its gets hot. I think the main problem is from Optimus technology (I have some display problems with it in Ubuntu 12.04 too!). Since I am not using my discrete GPU in Linux, therefore I have disabled it. There is two way to do this:

1.if there is no BIOS option to use UMA GPU only we must install `bumblebee` and required packages and then turn off discrete GPU.

2.if there is a BIOS option, we can disable Optimus. (there will be no problem with windows since it use UMA for all programs except programs you defined as "run with high-performance NVIDIA's GPU". So you can enable it from BIOS and come back to run them)

*first solution*:
do instructions from [here](http://smithfarm-thebrain.blogspot.cz/2013/03/opensuse-123-how-to-install-bumblebee.html)

*second solution*:
go to your BIOS and disable optimus. Then come back to linux and delete all nvidia packages. Check your hardware and make sure there is no nvidia's GPU

*another point*:
you can install YsST power management package for better controlling over power savings and therefore fan and temp of your laptop. Instructions are [here](https://forums.opensuse.org/blogs/jdmcdaniel3/yast-power-management-control-your-cpu-energy-usage-how-faq-28/)

I hope someday linux will support optimus technology like windows!